# Emails send through codeigniter email library are not coming on icloud email account

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, shared-hosting

I am using code igniter email library to send email, Emails sent to gmail account or yahoo account are working ok but when i try to sent the email on icloud account (ex. test171993@icloud.com) that email is not coming on  icloud account. I am using this code to send email

```
         $config = Array(
        'protocol' => 'SMTP',
        'smtp_host' => 'box397.bluehost.com',
        'smtp_port' => 587,
        'smtp_user' => 'info@virtualguestservices.com',//
        'smtp_pass' => '*********',// password of above email
        'mailtype' => 'html',
        'charset' => 'utf-8',
        'wordwrap' => TRUE
    );

    $message = '<h3>Hi,<br/><br/>
                We have received a request to reset the password for your account registered with User Id '.strtoupper($userId).'. You will be asked to change this password on login for security purpose.<br/><br/>
                Your new password is '.$newPassword.'.<br/><br/>Thanks</h3>';
    $this->load->library('email', $config);
    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
    $this->email->from('info@virtualguestservices.com');
    $this->email->to($emailAddress);
    $this->email->subject('Request for New Paswword.');
    $this->email->message($message);
    if($this->email->send())
    {
        $message = [ 
            'status' => 1,
            'message' => "New password has been sent to your email address.",
        ];
      $this->set_response($message,REST_Controller::HTTP_OK);
    }
    else
    {
        $message = [ 
            'status' => 0,
            'message' => show_error($this->email>print_debugger()),
        ];
        $this->set_response($message,REST_Controller::HTTP_OK);
    }
```

In short the problem is that mail are going to domains like gmail, yahoo but mail are not going to domains like icloud, at&t etc.

Comment: Check you email logs. Check if your domain has proper DNS records like SPF and DKIM.

Answer (score 0):

Check your headers you might missing some thing . Other domains might check strict.